# Better name for a method than "isThis()"

Tags: class, authentication, methods, naming-conventions, naming

I have one class called `OAuthLogin` that supports the login of a user via OAuth. The website supports also a "traditional" login process, without OAuth. The two flows share a lot of code, where I need to differentiate them sometimes.

I have a static method `OAuthLogin::isThis()` that returns a boolean whether the current login flow is OAuth or not (by checking session variables and URL parameters).

I don't like the name of the method but I can't think of a better one - I guess that is a common concept, therefore there should be some kind of pattern.

I don't like `OAuthLogin::isThisOAuthLogin()` because is redundant.

I would like to avoid `Login::isThisOAuth` because I would like to keep all the code in the `OAuthLogin` class.

Should I go for `OAuthLogin::is()`? Anything better than that?

Thanks.

Comment: OAuthLogin::isOAuthLogin() ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Your OAuthLogin class should only have [**one responsibility**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle), and that is to enable a user to login using OAuth; this class should have no knowledge of the "traditional" login process. A person who sees this class name (e.g. StackOverflow users!) will assume that this class is only responsible for login functionality using OAuth.

As your two login processes share a lot of code, then you really should refactor your code so that you have a base class with the common code, and then have separate classes for OAuth and Traditional login which will both inherit from the base class. When your code executes you should then instantiate the login class that is appropriate for that user's session.

Also as your OAuthLogin class is static then how will it be able to handle many users logging-in at the same time? Hence another good reason to refactor it so that it is not static.

If you absolutely cannot refactor, then without seeing your code, it sounds as if the OAuthLogin class is really a [**mediator**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern) i.e. it encapsulates how a set of classes interact (in this case your login classes). So instead of using the name "OAuthLogin" you could call it "LoginMediator". You could then have the properties:

```
LoginMediator.isOauthLogin
```

and

```
LoginMediator.isTraditionalLogin
```

to distinguish between the different types of login which the mediator is using for that particular session. Though instead of using the word "Traditional" replace this *with the other authentication mechanism you actually use* (e.g. HTTP Basic Authentication, HTTP Digest Authentication, HTTPS Client Authentication etc.)

Note how I have chosen [**intention-revealing**](http://www.itiseezee.com/?p=83) names for these properties. If a stranger was to read your code (e.g. me!) they would struggle to understand the purpose of "is()" and "isThis()" from just the method signature.

However, in the long run *I really do recommend* that you refactor your code so that you have classes with discrete responsibilities, as you will find that naming methods will be far easier as a result.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a method to the base class which just returns the type of the login.

Class (pseudo-code)

```
class Login
  method class
    return self.class # Returns the current class.
  end
end
```

Usage would be (also pseudo-code):

```
if currentLogin.class == OAuthLogin
  # ..
else
  # ..
end
```

This would let you add more types later on, without having to add type-specific methods for each login type, leaving the control flow outside of your classes.

Comment: What if I don't want to create a new class?

Comment: I don't get your question. You don't have to, you're putting the method into your base class (`Login`). But the way would be open if you'd do it in the future. Regardless, I'd choose that approach personally, because it keeps the process logic outside of the model.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest one of:

```
OAuthLogin::isCurrent()
OAuthLogin::isCurrentLogin()
OAuthLogin::isCurrentFlow()
OAuthLogin::isCurrentLoginFlow()
OAuthLogin::isActive()
OAuthLogin::isActiveLogin()
OAuthLogin::isActiveFlow()
OAuthLogin::isActiveLoginFlow()
```

Answer (score 0):

How about `OAuthLogin::isUsed()`?

Answer (score -1):

I suggest `OAUthLogin::isLoggedIn().`